# Is there a time limit on claiming medical expenses for HSA?

Tags: united-states, hsa

I use my HSA as a savings vehicle.

From what I'm reading it seems that there is no limit on the time between when the expense was incurred and when it can be claimed against an HSA except that you *had* an HSA when the expense was incurred.

Is it correct that I could save my medical receipts for many years then claim them all at once in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it correct that I could save my medical receipts for many years
>   then claim them all at once in the future?

Yes, that is correct. Save your receipts (or scan them and save the files).

I'm doing the same. I pay my expenses out of pocket for now, and use the HSA as a tax-free investment vehicle for retirement.

Once I'm retired, I expect to start using the HSA to pay my health expenses - either expenses incurred during retirement, or past expenses. We don't have lots of health expenses now, but I can't predict what they will be down the road. Either way, the HSA investments should help.

Plus they are funded pre-tax today, grow tax-free, and will be disbursed tax-free.

Comment: I presume that the caveat here is that if you intend to claim them later as pretax expenses you CAN'T have itemized them earlier, right?

Comment: @keshlam - hmm, that's a good question. I don't know. I don't itemize my medical expenses, so it doesn't apply to me. I'll have to research that one.

Comment: Just to cite a source for this, this is exactly what HSA provder companies are claiming in their FAQs: https://crewconnect.vanguard.com/totalrewards/benefits/healthandwellness/medical/hsa_faq_withdrawals.html